# What exactly did I do wrong with this script?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to run this script

```
from schoolclass import School
import elasticsearch
import elasticsearch_dsl as srch
import mysql.connector as mdb
es = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch()
cnx = mdb.connect(user= 'root', password= '*****', host= '127.0.0.1', database= 'sync-helper')
cursor = cnx.cursor(),
query = "SELECT Zip FROM school"
cursor.execute(query)
schools = list(cursor.fetchall())
zips = []
for z in schools:
    zips.append(str(z[0])

school = School(3, "Crystal", "Hillsborough", 94010)
print school.search(zips)
```

but python is saying that there is a syntax error, highlighting the school variable where it is being defined. How do I fix the syntax?

Comment: Missing `)` on the previous line: `zips.append(str(z[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `SyntaxError` means that somewhere in your code a statement is hasn't been constructed properly. In your case, `zips.append(str(z[0])` is missing a closing parenthesis. A good place to look when you have a `SyntaxError` is the line before the one indicated.

Comment: Thank you so much!